# RETURN VALUE FROM COLUMN WHERE FIRST ROW SHOWS TODAYS DATE

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to find a formula that will do the following: (I have looked!!)
First row across is Name, Indicator, then DATES moving forward.

First Column is Name
Second Column is a returned value from the adjacent columns if the date in the first row is todays date.

eg. ASSUMING 23/01/14

name     indicator      23/01/14   24/01/14
fred     NOR            NOR        NCU
JANE     NCU            NCU        NOR

SO IN ROW TWO NOR IN THE SECOND COLUMN IS RETURNING THE VALUE IN THE SECOND ROW WHERE THE DATE IS TODAY. CANNOT SEEM TO FIGURE IT OUT WITH IF FORMULA.

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The organization of the data in your question is not very clear, but I would guess that the HLOOKUP function is what you want.  See the screen snapshot below.

The HLOOKUP searches the first row of the range for the target, and returns the 2nd row corresponding item.

[image: HLOOKUP Screenshot]

Comment: Actually I probably should have explained it better like this:
On Sheet1 cell A2 is the date, in cells B3-B13 a name, in column C I need a formula that will look up sheet 2, in sheet 2 column 1 contains names and columns 3 onwards contain the dates going forward. Row 1 is the headers ie: date for matching from Sheet 1. I need the cell value to be returned where the name and date intersect in the range.